# Facebook API Data Import into Python then formatting in csv

Tags: python, facebook, api, csv

First of all, I want to emphasize that I'm a total novice to python and api (well programming in general).

I'm trying to come up with ways to automatically process inputs of facebook userids in csv format

i.e.)

dietpepsi

pepsi

cocacola

dietcoke

and then for the python script to spit out page informations also in csv format
with each value seperated by column

i.e.)
Name, Number of Likes, Number of people "Talking about this" etc...
Diet Pepsi, 709,788, 4,761, etc....

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import cookielib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json
import datetime
import urlparse
import operator
import sys
import csv
import io


input = open('input.csv', 'rU')
output = open ('cleaned_input.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
for row in csv.reader(input):
    if any(row):
        writer.writerow(row)
input.close()
output.close()

sharesoutput = open('results.csv', 'w')

with open('results.csv', 'w') as results:

    with open('cleaned_input.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

        for row in reader:
            myid='. '.join(row)
            try:
                myfile=urllib2.urlopen("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ myid)
                myjson=json.loads(myfile.read())
                names = myjson["name"]
                published = myjson["is_published"]
                likes = myjson["likes"]
                talkingabout = myjson["talking_about_count"]

                print names
                print likes
                print talkingabout
                print '\n'

                sharesoutput.write(names+"\t"+likes+"\t"+talkingabout+"\n")

            except:
                print "Error"

sharesoutput.close()
```

I tried a code like one above and it's printing values on the python shell but it's not properly saved in csv (it's blank)

If there is a way to save it in csv and also separate each kinds of values by column.. that would be great. Any help?

---

```
import urllib2
import json
import operator
import sys
import csv



sharesoutput = open('results.csv', 'w')

with open('input.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    for row in reader:
        myid='. '.join(row)
        try:
            myfile=urllib2.urlopen("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ myid)
            myjson=json.loads(myfile.read())
            names = myjson["name"]
            published = myjson["is_published"]
            likes = myjson["likes"]
            talkingabout = myjson["talking_about_count"]

            print names
            print likes
            print talkingabout
            print '\n'

            sharesoutput.write(names+"\t"+likes+"\t"+talkingabout+"\n")

        except:
            print "Error"

sharesoutput.close()
```

Fixed some stuff per Felipe's suggestions
Still a blank csv...

Comment: You're opening two handles to `results.csv`. One in the `with` statement and one in `sharesoutput`. Get rid of the latter and see if it still happens.

Comment: Also, for future reference, try paring down the code to essentials. Unused imports don't need to be there, and neither does the input cleaning part.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I copied this from another script I had that's why there are some superfluous parts

Comment: Another point (forgot to write it earlier) is to **never** use a bare `except` clause. It's also good practice to only catch exceptions you can handle.

Comment: Is your "error" message getting printed?

Answer (score 0):

open the sharesoutput file in append mode. 
ie.,

```
sharesoutput = open('results.csv', 'a')
```